# How to install a package from source (e.g. nmap 7.60) and first fix unresolved dependencies on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, nmap

I found myself wanting to [install nmap 7.60](https://packages.debian.org/sid/nmap) bc it has really neat functionality for scanning IPs for information on my local network (USED RESPONSIBLY, of course), but 16.04 does not support v7.60 out of the box due to many unresolved dependencies. I can't figure out how to resolve those dependencies. This happens quite a bit with source packages I want to install in Ubuntu.

The nmap website has [instructions indicating I should use unstable debian repositories](https://nmap.org/book/inst-linux.html#inst-debian). Although, as you see from the initial downvotes, that is considered a really bad practice. I can't figure out how to get what I need without unintentionally opening up my OS to really bad long term side effects.

So, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surest way to install the latest Nmap no matter what system you run is to [build from source](https://nmap.org/book/inst-source.html). Just make sure you have a C/C++ compiler and the OpenSSL development headers installed. One easy way to make sure you have the build dependencies on Ubuntu and Debian systems is to run `sudo apt-get build-dep nmap`. This will fetch and install the build dependency packages for Nmap, which ought to work fine.

Comment: THAT... is what I was missing: `sudo apt-get build-dep nmap` Sucks to everyone else's downvotes. Without that little tidbit of knowledge, I was following the _nmap site instructions_ to use the unstable 7.60 package from the debian repository. :P

Comment: If you want to use dpkg to manage the installation, use `checkinstall` to wrap the installation in a .deb package. Works great for most stuff you build from source.

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT: I leave this here only because it is a shining example of *WHAT NOT TO DO*.**

First, I add this to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid main
```

Then, `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install nmap`.

To test, I run this to scan my LAN:

```
sudo nmap -O 192.168.0.100-109
```

After a couple minutes (on a slow machine) I will get a list of IPs with OSs and MAC Addresses. Woohoo!

Comment: This will brake your system on next upgrade(s). Mixing debian and ubuntu repositories is bad idea. I recommend to disable this debian line in sources.list just after installation of zenmap. Or set pin-priority.

Comment: I am running an ARMv7 Arch with Ubuntu Make 16.04 - This is the only option that I found actually does the job. From here, I am making an image of all the installed packages on the hardened OS and replicating to other eMMC source drives throughout my cluster architecture.